# How to choose between a dictionary with integer keys in range(n) and a list of length n?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**Short version of the question:**

When comparing a dictionary for which the keys are integers in range(n) and a list of length n, which are the key points of an implementation to choose between one or the other? Things like "if you are doing a lot of this thing with your object, then a dictionary is better".

**Long version of the question**

I'm not sure if the following details of my implementation matter for the question... So here it is.
In trying to make my code a bit more pythonic, I implemented a subclass of UserList that accepts as index both an integer and a list that represents an integer in base l.

```
from collections import UserList

class MyList(UserList):
    """
    A list that can be accessed both by a g-tuple of coefficients in range(l)
    or the corresponding integer.
    """
    def __init__(self, data=None, l=2, g=None):
        self.l = l
        if data == None:
            if g == None:
                raise ValueError
            self.data = [0]*(l**g)
        else:
            self.data = data
        
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            self.data[key] = value
        else:
            self.data[self.idx(key)] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return self.data[key]
        return self.data[self.idx(key)]

    def idx(self, key):
        l = self.l
        idx = 0
        for i, value in enumerate(key):
            idx += value*l**i
        return idx
```

Which can be used like this:

```
L = MyList(l=4, g=2) #creates a list of length 4**2 initialized at zero
L[9] = 'Hello World'
L[9] == L[1,2]
```

I have generalized this class to also accept `l` to be a tuple of bases (let's call this generalized class `MyListTuple`), but the code is in SageMath so I don't really want to translate that to pure python too, but it works great.

It would look something like this:

```
L = MyListTuple(l=[2,4], g=2) #creates a list of length 2^2*4^2 initialized at zero
L[0,9] = 'Hello World'
L[0,9] == L[[0,0],[1,2]]
```

The next part I want to improve I currently use a dictionary of which the keys are tuples of integers (so you would access it as `d[9,13,0]`), but I want to also be able to use as (equivalent) keys lists representing the integer in base l as above (so for l=4 that would be `d[[1,2], [1,3], [0,0]]`).

This is very similar to what I have done in `MyListTuple`, but in this case, a lot of the keys are never used.

So my question is: How to choose between creating a subclass of UserDict that is equivalent to MyListTuple in handling the given key or just use MyListTuple even if in most cases most entries will never be used?
Or as I phrased it above, which are the details in the use of this structure that I should look for to choose between the two? (things like "if you are doing a lot of this thing with your object, then a dictionary is better")

Answer (score 0):

(Will only try to address the general "list vs dict" part.
Take this with a grain of salt; from user, not implementer.
This is not a real answer, more of a big comment.)

List (probably doubly-linked list) should provide efficient
insertion & deletion anywhere (only modifying pointers to
next/prev elements, O(1)).
Searching will be ineffecient (both O(n) -check all items-,
and cache misses* -bad locality of reference-).
(*vs items stored contiguously in memory (e.g. numpy.array)).

Dict (some kind of hash-map) should theoretically provide
efficient searches, insertions & deletions (amortized O(1));
but that may depend on the quality of the hash function, the
bucket size, the usage patterns, etc. (I don't know enough).

Iterating through all items sequentially will be inefficient
for both, due to cache misses / bad locality of reference
(following pointers, instead of accessing memory sequentially).

As far as I know:
You would use lists as mutable sequences (when you need to
iterate over all items) in Python, for lack of a better
alternative (C arrays, C++ std::array/std::vector/, etc.).
You would use dicts for quick lookup/search, based on keys,
when searching is more important/often, than insertion/deletion.

Comment: Do your indexes go up from zero with no gaps? Then use a list. Is your starting index negative or greater than zero,  or are there gaps? Use a dict.

Comment: @BoarGules Good point: if the integer indices can have negative or non-contiguous values, then list can't be used directly (not without mapping the indices to something appropriate for list).